# Microsoft Graph API Create Group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When creating a new group that is NOT security enabled is it possible to create the group with mailEnabled set too false?

When creating the group the API seems to ignore the mailEnabled field in the request and always returns true.  Also when attempting to patch the group with mailEnabled=false the api returns 204 but the mailEnabled never changes from true too false.

Is this a bug or is it simply not possible to have a mailEnabled=false group even though there is an option flag.

Answer (score 0):

Although this may not be a direct answer, I would try creating the group as mail-enabled:false via the GUI. If it allows you to do this then you can confirm that the API is not working as expected.

Have a look here as well:
[Mail-enable](https://serverfault.com/questions/912746/how-to-mail-enable-an-existing-azure-ad-security-group)

From reading this, it seems like the mailEnabled attribute cannot receive a PATCH via the Graph API